# Issues with nginx and node apps started through systemd in aws

Tags: node.js, nginx, redhat, systemd

I have a node app that runs and converts html string to pdf and returns a download link. It's fronted by nginx and locally (on my mac) everything works without flaw. On aws redhat linux I can't get the node app to work without some form of permissions error or timeout.
When i start the node process by hand and not through systemd then I don't get any timeouts, however the font doesn't show up in the generated pdf( thats another issue). When I start through systemd then i get timeouts and logs don't tell me enough to know what or why.
I've been at this for a week now fixing some errors and finding others and I'm at wits end. Can someone please tell me what you need in terms of information to help out. Selinux is currently set to permissive as I try to work through things.

gist of all the config files

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d983e3badaa264e64a0e

systemd error log for api service

2016/02/29 13:51:44 [error] 3776#0: *29 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 198.246.153.102, server: ip-172-31-28-51.us-west-2.compute.internal, request: "POST /api/v.1.0.0/createPdf HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3030/v.1.0.0/createPdf", host: "52.37.111.58", referrer: "http://52.37.111.58/"

the render tier access log

2016/02/29 14:23:01 [warn] 4517#0: *2 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/tmp/0000000002 while reading upstream, client: 198.246.153.102, server: ip-172-31-28-51.us-west-2.compute.internal, request: "GET /dist/main-8c26aa183d856d3d3955.js.map HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/main-8c26aa183d856d3d3955.js.map", host: "52.37.111.58"

Comment: Same version of node in both environments? What version?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the instance and my timeouts issue went away. For the issue with the pdf rendering with no characters thats been solved by installing missing font libraries.

```
yum install libXext libXrender xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-fonts-75dpicode
```